# Binary tree method and node

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, nodes

From the code bellow i want to add  a method to the LinkedBinaryTree class that returns the height of a tree and another method in BTNode that does most of the work. First, check to see if the root is null. If it is, then the tree is obviously empty and return 0. If it is not null, return root.height().

```
   import java.util.Iterator;


public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTree<T>
{
   protected BTNode<T> root;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty binary tree.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree()
   {
      root = null;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a binary tree with the specified element as its root.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree (T element)
   {
      root = new BTNode<T>(element);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a binary tree with the two specified subtrees.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree (T element, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left,
      LinkedBinaryTree<T> right)
   {
      root = new BTNode<T>(element);
      root.setLeft(left.root);
      root.setRight(right.root);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the element stored in the root of the tree. Throws an
   //  EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public T getRootElement()
   {
      if (root == null)
         throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get root operation "
            + "failed. The tree is empty.");

      return root.getElement();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the left subtree of the root of this tree.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getLeft()
   {
      if (root == null)
         throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get left operation "
            + "failed. The tree is empty.");

      LinkedBinaryTree<T> result = new LinkedBinaryTree<T>();
      result.root = root.getLeft();

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the element in this binary tree that matches the
   //  specified target. Throws a ElementNotFoundException if the
   //  target is not found.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public T find (T target)
   {
      BTNode<T> node = null;

      if (root != null)
         node = root.find(target);

      if (node == null)
         throw new ElementNotFoundException("Find operation failed. "
            + "No such element in tree.");

      return node.getElement();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the number of elements in this binary tree.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int size()
   {
      int result = 0;

      if (root != null)
         result = root.count();

      return result;
   }



 public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator<T>();
    }

}
```

Comment: So then, what's your question? What have you tried? This is not a "give me the code" site. Please read the "[what topics can I ask about?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" page. If you have a _specific_ question ("I did X and expected A but got B"), you can ask that here (but please search first, because it may have already been asked).

Comment: I dont see any main method? how do i run this code then?

Comment: Um, write a main method. :)